# Recursive Python Simple Function

Tags: python, string, function, recursion

I'm doing the MIT Intro to CS class to learn python and am stuck on a problem set involving recursive programming(calling a function within itself). The goal is to find a number of occurrences for a given target string. I have the following code and from my logic it seems like it should but I can't figure out why it doesn't! Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

```
def countSubStringMatchRecursive(target,key):
    answers = []
    match = target.find(key)

    if match != -1:
        answers.append(match)
        next_target = target[match+1:]
        countSubStringMatchRecursive(next_target,key)

    return len(answers)
```

So for given arguments:

```
target1 = 'mjzzmjzzmj'
key1 = 'zz'

print(countSubStringMatchRecursive(target1, key1))
```

I get 1 instead of the correct answer of two.

This is on Python3 btw.

Comment: Please explain exactly how your code fails. Does it crash? Return the wrong data? (Example input/output/expected)

Comment: Do you just want the count, or do you want the indices? What about overlapping matches, e.g. 'aba' occurs twice in 'ababa' if you allow for overlaps.

Comment: See edit. I get a wrong answer. I'm looking for the count here.

Comment: You're getting a final result of 1 because you're not returning the answers up through the call chain, so it only returns 0 or 1, depending on whether or not there are _any_ occurrences.

Comment: answers[] needs to be outside of your method creation. Otherwise, each time it is creating a new one

Comment: What do you mean by call chain? Wouldn't my answers list hold all values until the final return statement?

Comment: @MJ49, only if you use a shared answers list for all calls, and that would be cheating at recursion :). You don't even need the list, since all you want is the count. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't need the answers.. you don't need the answers; just a count.

```
from __future__ import print_function


def countSubStringMatchRecursive(target, key):
    match = target.find(key)

    if match != -1:
        next_target = target[match+1:]
        return 1 + countSubStringMatchRecursive(next_target, key)
    else:
        return 0


print(countSubStringMatchRecursive('asd asd asd', 'sd'))  # 3
print(countSubStringMatchRecursive('ababa', 'ab'))  # 2
```

This does count overlapping matches; let me know if that's not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Cause your variable "answer" is in the body of the function. Hence every time you call the function, it will be reset as "answer=[]"

```
answers=[]

def countSubStringMatchRecursive(target,key):
    match = target.find(key)

    if match != -1:
        global answers
        answers.append(match)
        next_target = target[match+1:]
        countSubStringMatchRecursive(next_target,key)

    return len(answers)

target1 = 'mjzzmjzzmj'
key1 = 'zz'

print(countSubStringMatchRecursive(target1, key1))
```